# WSO2 ESB 4.8 JMS Proxy with durable subscription on Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I have a JMS Proxy with durable subscription to ActiveMQ working perfectly in WSO2 ESB v4.5.1 and v4.7

I'm trying to use it in WSO2 ESB v4.8.0 (Milestone 3 or 4) with no success

Before starting ESB, topic isn't defined into ActiveMQ and there is no durable subscriber referenced (0 offline subscriber in ActiveMQ console)

The JMS proxy in ESB :

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestJMSProxy" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
          <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>text/xml</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myTopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">topic</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">MY_TOPIC</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberName">TestJMSProxy</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">consumer</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberClientID">1</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The JMS config in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml :

```
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
    <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
          <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
          <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="default" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
          <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

--> I've been using tcp://localhost:61616 and nio://localhost:61616 with the sames effetcs

The error seen in ESB console :

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-10-25 12:04:00,077] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Error acquiring a JMS connection to : TopicConnectionFactory using JNDI properties : {java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, serviceType=proxy, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=myTopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, java.naming.provider.url=failover:tcp://localhost:61616}
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager.handleException(ServiceTaskManager.java:1000)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager.access$2500(ServiceTaskManager.java:50)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConnection(ServiceTaskManager.java:830)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getConnection(ServiceTaskManager.java:703)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:493)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

--> several times before java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

The error seen in ActiveMQ logs :

```
2013-10-25 12:03:58,905 | WARN  | Failed to add Connection ID:JMROUSSEL7-64437-1382695110115-21:1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:64803@61616
javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: 1 already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:64802
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addConnection(RegionBroker.java:243)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addConnection(AdvisoryBroker.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:733)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

--> several times

I've tried ActiveMQ 5.7 and ActiveMQ 5.9, no difference

You just have to change this line in the JMS proxy and it works perfectly in WSO2 ESB v4.8 : `<parameter name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</parameter>`

A JMS proxy reading from a queue or a Message Store / Message Processor works perfectly in WSO2 ESB 4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, I've created this jira : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2638 ant it will be resolved in final 4.8.0 version from the ESB